# How do I get intellisense to pop up?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How do I get intellisense to pop up while I am coding?

I know it pops up when I start typing a known type, e.g.,
if I type <kbd>NSS</kbd> it will finish it for me `NSString`.
How do I get it to give me a bunch of options like in Visual Studio, e.g.,
if I type <kbd>NS</kbd> I want to see what my options are like `NSString`, `NSInteger`, etc?

And if I have not typed anything, I still want a bunch of options like all the instance variables, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press the escape key.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the escape key, you might want to look at the Xcode preferences, there is a "Code Sense" tab with some configuration options.